# Deleted my .mdf file in App_Data in an attempt to refresh database. Project is now broken

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I was looking for a method to refresh the projects 'code-first' .mdf and deleted the file hoping that upon rebuilding the project, it would build a new one.

Now lists that were once displaying my data are empty and if I attempt create a new object I get JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined.

How do I reset the project to generate a new database like when I compiled it for the first time?

Many thanks

Comment: This is for visual studio 2010 right?

Comment: Have you tried running the 'ASP.NET Configuration' tool? (It's in the solution explorer and in the menu 'Project') Don't know if it helps. Otherwise you could perhaps create a new project and use the mdf generated via the new one to make it the most easy.

Comment: @Silvermind - Thanks, I'll have a look at this tomorrow.