# Deleted .mdf file under App_Data in Visual Studio 2013. Now what?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio, mdf, app-data

I'm working on a small tutorial app using ASP.NET and MVC 5. I was finding that the database wasn't updating when I changed my seed data. Also, I put a breakpoint in the initializer class, and never hit it. I figured, well if I delete the database, then it will just get made fresh like it did when I first created it. Wrong. It broke the project. Same thing happened to [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786158/deleted-my-mdf-file-in-app-data-in-an-attempt-to-refresh-database-project-is-n).

What do I do now? Surely there is a way to get VS to create a new database.

Comment: Hmm maybe just create a new project and copy&paste the database generated for it?

Comment: I got: "System.NotSupportedException: Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations." The line cited is `return View(db.Students.ToList());`